# How to group request javax validations?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-rest, javax.validation

I have test spring-boot-starter-validation behaviour and noticed that: request body is validated first throwing a WebExchangeBindException and then request path&query parameters are validated throwing a ConstraintViolationException. So, how to join these two groups of constraints in a single Exception catched in a single response body?

Expected response body:

```
{
  "address": "must not be blank",
  "mail": "must be a well-formed email address",
  "floor": "floor cannot be null",
  "control.mark": "must be less than or equal to 5",
  "control.infect": "must be greater than 0",
  "control.age": "must be greater than or equal to 5"
}
```

Actual request body fields constraints:

```
{
  "address": "must not be blank",
  "mail": "must be a well-formed email address",
  "floor": "floor cannot be null"
}
```

Actual query and path parameters constraints:

```
{
  "control.mark": "must be less than or equal to 5",
  "control.infect": "must be greater than 0",
  "control.age": "must be greater than or equal to 5"
}
```

Here is an integration test for a better understanding [link](https://github.com/luckypier/spring-validation-poc/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/poc/library/BookIT.java)

Dependencies:

- spring-boot version 2.7.2
- spring-boot-starter-webflux
- spring-boot-starter-validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use one unified `ConstraintViolationException` exception and gather all constraints into one group.

It is possible via [@Validated(Group.class)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html) annotation. [Validation group documentation](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-groupsequence).

**1. Create an interface for your validation group**

```java
public interface Group {
}
```

**2.Apply group for your `RestController`**

```java
@RestController
@Validated
@Slf4j
public class BookController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/control/{age}/mark/{mark}")
    @Validated(Group.class)
    public Object control(
            @PathVariable("age")
            @Min(value = 5, groups = Group.class) Integer age,

            @PathVariable("mark")
            @Max(value = 5, groups = Group.class) Integer mark,

            @Min(value = 3, groups = Group.class) @RequestParam(name = "conclusion") Integer conclusion,

            @Positive(groups = Group.class) @RequestParam(name = "infect") Integer infect,

            @Valid
            @RequestBody Book book
    ) {

      return new Book();
    }
}
```

**3. Apply group for your transfer object**

```java
@Data
public class Book {

    @NotBlank(groups = Group.class)
    private String address;

    @NotNull(message = "floor cannot be null", groups = Group.class)
    private String floor;

    @Email(groups = Group.class)
    private String mail;
}
```

**Output:**

```json
{
  "control.mark": "must be less than or equal to 5",
  "control.book.mail": "must be a well-formed email address",
  "control.infect": "must be greater than 0",
  "control.book.floor": "floor cannot be null",
  "control.book.address": "must not be blank",
  "control.age": "must be greater than or equal to 5"
}
```